# How do I write a monkey patch for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

I am using Rails 3 and getting an error that looks like this:

```
undefined method `persisted?' for []:Array
```

I want to monkeypatch to fix this problem. First of all: what is it supposed to look like? I know very little about the nesting of the Array class in Ruby's source code. I'd appreciate the guidance.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. That error suggests that you are passing an array (of ActiveRecord objects?) to a function which is expecting a single ActiveRecord object.

Comment: Gareth: thank you! do you know how I could patch this problem? I'd appreciate any guidance. I'm getting this weird error in Mongoid doing nested forms.

Comment: Not without seeing more of the code and/or the error trace

Comment: This is the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175206/rails-3-having-an-error-with-nested-forms-with-mongoid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

basically you just write the class and function like you would for any other class and it gets added to the original class definition.

Like So:

```
class Array
    def persisted?
        # Does it persist?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Monkey-patching looks like this:

```
# patches/array.rb
class Array # Array is a top-level class
  def persisted?
    false # or your own implementation
  end
end

# some/other/script.rb
require 'path/to/patches/array.rb'
my_array = [1, 2, 3]
puts my_array.persisted?
```

Now: what can you possibly mean by asking an Array instance whether it is persisted?